# MySQL trigger: conditional insert syntax error

Tags: mysql, relational-database, database-trigger

I have two tables: *Person* and *Student*. I am trying to write a trigger which, after inserting a new person, inserts into the student table if the person is less than 18 years old.

Here is the code of the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON Person
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into `Student`(TestValue, ID) 
values("Test", select Person.ID from Person where Person.DateOfBirth > curdate() - interval 18 year);
END
```

But I keep getting the

> You have an error in your SQL syntax... near `select Person.ID from...interval 18 year`.

error, and I don't know if it's because of the conditional inserting, or the datetime operation, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON Person
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into `Student`(TestValue, ID) 
select "Test", Person.ID from Person where Person.DateOfBirth > curdate() - interval 18 year;
END
```

You can't have a `SELECT` clause as an argument in `VALUES`.
But you can have "Test" as a value in your select...

Answer (score 2):

You wanted to use `insert into ... select from` construct like below and can't mix both `insert into .. values` construct with

```
insert into `Student`(TestValue, ID) 
select "Test", Person.ID 
from Person 
where Person.DateOfBirth > curdate() - interval 18 year;
```